Users are automatically added to a case queue in Salesforce without any apparent automation
I’m experiencing an issue with queue management in Salesforce. Currently, I manage several case queues, each associated with a group of users who share records among themselves.
A few months ago, I created a new queue and manually assigned only two users to it. However, I’ve noticed that other users are automatically added to this queue from time to time, usually after they log in (although not always immediately). If I remove these users, they eventually reappear in the queue after a few days.
To troubleshoot this, I have:
Reviewed automation flows, business processes, workflow rules, and related triggers.
Verified that there is no automation configuration or custom code adding users to this queue.
Despite these checks, users continue to appear in the queue without any clear reason. I also created a case with Salesforce support, but they couldn’t identify the cause.
Has anyone experienced a similar issue or have any ideas on how I can stop this behavior?
Thank you in advance for your help.

Did you look in Setup > Login Flows also?  Do you have any external integrations that touch user-related items?  I can't remember if queue assignments are tracked in Audit Trail, but you could take a look for more info.

Hi @DavidCheng, yes, I already checked the login flows, and there’s nothing; there is no integration related to users. In the audit trail, I can see the login, and a few seconds later after the login, they add themselves to the queue.

And you checked for old Process Builders, right?  Do you have any managed packages that might be doing this?  Does this happen for every new queue you create?  If you can replicate the issue easily, capture a debug log to see if there's more detail.

Yes, I checked all the automation tools, and I don’t have any related to queues or users. This only happens with this queue; I have about eight more queues, and the others are fine.

Have you tried checking the Setup Audit Trail to see which user is updating the queue membership? It might help narrow it down at least.

Manager of Queue Member? see Trailblazer question/answer

Thanks for you reply @CallumMacErlich, the same user adds themselves to the queue according to the audit trail.

Hi @cropredy, thanks for you replay. I don't have any Queue Manager, which is strange because the same user adds themselves to the queue."
